# Cannot install Adobe CS5 - install hangs at calculating time

Tags: install, performance, adobe-photoshop

I am not able to install any of the Adobe CS5 software. The installer hangs when calculating time.

Here's what I found in the installer log:

```
[       0] Mon Oct  3 21:22:13 2011  INFO
::START TIMER:: [Total Timer]
CHECK: Single instance running
CHECK : Credentials
Load Deployment File
Create Required Folders
Assuming install mode
::START TIMER:: [Bootstrap]
Perform Bootstrapping ...
[       0] Mon Oct  3 21:36:16 2011  INFO
::START TIMER:: [Total Timer]
CHECK: Single instance running
CHECK : Credentials
Load Deployment File
Create Required Folders
Assuming install mode
::START TIMER:: [Bootstrap]
Perform Bootstrapping ...
[       0] Tue Oct  4 00:14:07 2011  INFO
::START TIMER:: [Total Timer]
CHECK: Single instance running
CHECK : Credentials
Load Deployment File
Create Required Folders
Assuming install mode
::START TIMER:: [Bootstrap]
Perform Bootstrapping ...
```

Every time it tries to perform Bootstrapping, it hangs right there.

I've also tried to download a trial version of Photoshop only and install it through Adobe Download Assistant, but still the same results (see the last entry in the log).

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: You don't have a case sensitive filesystem by any chance?

Comment: not sure, don't think I changed anything since I got my Mac 2 days ago, but I managed to install the trial version of Photoshop. Will try again with the whole CS5 collection, hope it works. I don't know why it behaved strange.

Comment: Yeah that is strange, CS5 won't install if its a case sensitive file system. But if its a new machine, that won't be the case. If you managed to get the trial installed the full version should work now.

Comment: Yes the full version worked as well. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same hanging problem when I tried to install InDesign and Photoshop CS5 5 on two iMacs (both 24-inch, early 2009 models with 4GB RAM) that I have formatted to install El Capitan.
From a tip I read somewhere, I installed Java that I downloaded from this link: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US
You have to restart the computer after installing Java. InDesign installed without a hitch after that. Photoshop hanged twice on one iMac but on the third try, after another restart, Photoshop successfully installed. 
If this remedy failed, I would have tried the solutions mentioned here: [Installation of Adobe Creative Suite 6 hangs at AdobeHelp on Mac OS X El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208730/installation-of-adobe-creative-suite-6-hangs-at-adobehelp-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan)

Comment: You can download [Adobe CS5 Download](https://fileparrots.blogspot.com/2017/08/download-adobe-photoshop-cs5-free.html) Full Version Free, it will work properly.