# Installation of Adobe Creative Suite 6 hangs at AdobeHelp on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: install, performance, macos, adobe

I have been attempting to install Adobe Creative Suite 6 Production Premium after upgrading to Mac OS X El Capitan.

The installation seems to go along flawlessly until it attempts to install "AdobeHelp". Running `ps -aux` shows the the following command remains executing:

```
/Volumes/CS6\ ProdPrm/Adobe\ CS6\ Production\ Premium/payloads/AdobeHelp/InstallAdobeHelp appVersion=4.0.244 appId=chc pubId=4875E02D9FB21EE389F73B8D1702B320485DF8CE.1 installerArg1=-silent installerArg2=-eulaAccepted installerArg3=AdobeHelp.air
```

I tried killing the process, ([As suggested for the same issue on Windows](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1008411)) however this had no effect.

I tried manually running the command, (With `sudo`) which output the following on first attempt and then ceased execution:

```
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x29441d0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x29437f0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x29497c0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x2949090
2015-10-02 12:10:28.713 Adobe AIR Installer[564:9294] !!! BUG: The current event queue and the main event queue are not the same. Events will not be handled correctly. This is probably because _TSGetMainThread was called for the first time off the main thread.
```

And then this on the second attempt and remained executing indefinitely:

```
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x282c2e0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x281af40
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x282e110, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x282d9e0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x422b90, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x421ee0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x423470, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x423450
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this issue:

1. Restart the system, as the installer had to be force quit, and could not be relaunched easily.
2. Mount the `ProductionPremium_CS6_LS7.dmg` disk image. (Or I assume [any of the other CS6 products](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/cs6-product-downloads.html))
3. In Finder navigate to `CS6 ProdPrm`, then `Adobe CS6 Production Premium`, then `payloads`, then `AdobeHelp`, and execute `Adobe Air Install.app`.
4. Once the previous step is complete navigate to `CS6 ProdPrm`, then `Adobe CS6 Production Premium`, then `payloads`, then `AdobeHelp`, and execute `AdobeHelp.air`.

   *Note: As [Karl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/150578/karl) [pointed out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208730/installation-of-adobe-creative-suite-6-hangs-at-adobehelp-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/209289#209289), the AIR installer bundled with certain CS6 products may not install on Mac OS X El Capitan. If this is the case, you will need to navigate to https://get.adobe.com/air/ and and download and install Adobe AIR.*
5. Once the previous step is complete navigate to `CS6 ProdPrm`, then `Adobe CS6 Production Premium`, and run `Install.app`.

Comment: Note that Adobe Air will also auto-update itself when first launch as it detects a new version is available, so step 4 could be modified to be "allow adobe Air to update itself if requested"

Answer (score 3):

The above answer almost worked fully for me. Basically I think the biggest problem is the Adobe Air. The one included with the CS6 installer just wouldn't install. I downloaded the most recent version of Adobe Air from Adobe.com and installed that and then followed step 4 of the instruction above:

4. Once the previous step is complete navigate to CS6 ProdPrm, then Adobe CS6 Production Premium, then payloads, then AdobeHelp, and execute AdobeHelp.air

Once this was installed, I was able to install CS6 normally with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have found another and somewhat easier solution to this issue. I have been trying to install DesignStandard_CS6 and experienced the same issue, with the installer hanging at AdobeHelp. I tried navigating to the /Volumes/CS6 DesignStd/Adobe CS6 Design Standard/payloads/AdobeHelp and just running the Adobe AIR Installer. I found it was blocked by the Security & Privacy setting "Allow apps downloaded from:" which was set to the default "Mac App Store and identified developers".

This gave me the idea to change this setting to "Anyway" and hey presto, the installer completed when I tried it again.

I have not tried and tested this beyond my case, but it seems to make sense that this is what was causing it to hang.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem installing **Photoshop CS5** on **Mac OS 10.11 "El Capitan"**. The installer would hang at `AdobeHelp`. After completing the above steps mentioned by *Andrew* and *Karl*, I was finally able to get the install to proceed but only after making a few additional tweaks. Following is a brief summary of the entire procedure I followed:

1. Download the most recent version of `Adobe Air` from Adobe.com.
2. Mount the downloaded image and install `Adobe Air` by executing `Adobe Air Installer.app`.
3. Reboot.
4. Mount the `Photoshop_12_LS1.dmg` disk image.
5. Navigate to the mounted volume `Adobe Photoshop CS5/Adobe Photoshop CS5/payloads/AdobeHelp/` then execute `AdobeHelp.air`.
6. Allow `AdobeHelp` to update when prompted.

### This is the part I had to figure out for CS5:

7. Copy the contents of the installer image `Adobe Photoshop CS5` to your local disk by holding `option` and dragging it to the desktop.
8. Once copying is complete, navigate to `~/Desktop/Adobe Photoshop CS5/Adobe Photoshop CS5/payloads/AdobeHelp/` and replace the `Adobe AIR Installer.app` with the version of the file downloaded from Adobe.com.
9. Proceed with the installation by executing `Install.app` in the `Adobe Photoshop CS5` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution.. after multiple hangups and no progress, updated air and java which did not help.  After this, I discovered that when you open the installation process, if you select the individual apps you are installing and uncheck the processes in the photo below, it doesn't hang up and installs just fine and runs perfectly well.. at first I thought it was the extra system font package in those areas that was causing the hangup, but then when I installed dreamweaver, the first time it hung up when I left the two extras checked, then unchecked, the app installed and ran perfectly fine.. this may be a solid solution until Adobe addresses it..(if they do, regardless of those elitists who say the program is years old, it was still a big investment for me so I would like to get more use out of it).. also, I installed most of the suite using this method, everything is functional except After Effects, but, I had the same issue with it on the older system and oddly found the previous version of AE worked just fine, which is ok by me as I get most of what I need from Premiere  [image]